# Zsh backward-delete-word does not recognize "/" character

Tags: zsh

I want ctrl-W on Zsh to stop when it encounters the "/" character. I have the following in my .zshrc file, but it doesn't stop on "/". What is going on?

```
default-backward-delete-word () {
  local WORDCHARS="*?_[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>"
  zle backward-delete-word
}
zle -N default-backward-delete-word
bindkey '^W' default-backward-delete-word
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is, that `/` is part of your `WORDCHARS`.

According to `zshparam(1)`:

> **WORDCHARS** `<S>`
>
> A list of non-alphanumeric characters considered part of a word by the line editor.

So if you want *zsh* to consider `/` as a word separator, it should not be in `WORDCHARS`. I would also suggest using single quotes instead of double quotes when defining it - especially as there is a `$` in there, which may lead to unwanted expansions.

```
local WORDCHARS='*?_[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'
```